# Drupal language-switcher not adding prefixes

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm really stumped here.

I've created a page with 3 languages, but the language switcher will not work properly. 
I have translated both the menu entries and the content, and I want to use the language switcher to change both the menu item language and the content language.

What is happening now:
The language switcher points the browser to the node with the content translated, but the menu items are not working.

Or more exactly, the are for english, not russian.

I have in total 3 languages: Latvian, Russian and English, with Latvian as default. When I create some content in Latvian and the corresponding menu items, all is well. When I translate it into English, and add the menu items for English, all is well too, but the prefix for the link is not added. Since I'm using PathAuto, I believed, that that the language switcher would be using the newly generated node alias, but it is not. It is simply pointing to the node in English. But that is not the worst part.

When I select Russian, the content is translated, but none of the menu items appear. Also, sometimes, the prefix is added for russian, and then I can't revert back to Latvian, since there are no prefixes added for the default language, and the node alias is not displayed, only the node ID.

Any Ideas of how could I fix this? It is the only thing standing between me and completion of a project.

P.S. It almost seems, that Drupal was not made for this kind of a thing.
P.P.S I solved the problem for 2 languages - renamed English to Russian, since the client doesn't need English right now. I know, short term fix, but otherwise, my whole work would be in ruins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the template I was using. It rewrote all of the url's for beauty purposes, but didn't add prefixes correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone else has a similar problem.

I fixed the language switcher issue by adding a path prefix for english.

My site's default language is spanish and I have english as a second one. I Installed everything, add the english prefix and followed the instructions of this site: http://openflows.com/blog/mvc/2008/10/03/drupal-6-i18n-basics

the prefix issue is discussed here: http://drupal.org/node/354069

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add the prefix for your languages by going to `/admin/settings/language/edit/en`
I had the same problem and this saved me the hassle of going and fixing it from the template.

Comment: Equivalent link for Drupal 7: `/admin/config/regional/language/edit/en`